# Entity framework, how to manage errors for all the application?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Hi have a WPF application that use a **singleton** for use the entity framework in all the application without using always the `using(DbContext ctx =... )`

```
public static MyEntityDatabase db = new MyEntityDatabase();

App.db.TableXXX.Where(...)...
```

But, how i can manage errors for all the application in a single event? I don't want use a try-catch on every single database request or update.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think singleton DataContext is a good idea. Change tracking can make it slow after a while.

Comment: It's not a problem because the program is not database intensive. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Application.DispatcherUnhandledException Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) to do that. All you have to do is add a method name `App_DispatcherUnhandledException` to `App` class (app.xaml.cs.)

```
void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: I tried it but if  i close my MySQL server the exception is not catched by the unhandled exception handler. Why?

Comment: Because your application is not connecting to MySQL at the time you shutdown the service. If you search or update data (after shutting it down,) then you will get an exception.

Comment: nono i say exactly when AFTER i close the server i ask some data to the server and i got a provider exception but is visual studio intercepting it, not my method.